# How to trim specific characters from the end of the JavaScript string?

Tags: javascript, string, trim

In JavaScript, how do I trim from the right(string end)?

I have the following example:

```
var s1 = "this is a test~";
var s = s1.rtrim('~');
```

Comment: Top hit on google: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript

Comment: JavaScript now has `trimEnd()` and `trimStart()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimEnd • https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimStart

Comment: What browsers do support `trimEnd()` → https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_string_trimend

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Use a RegExp. Don't forget to escape special characters.

```
s1 = s1.replace(/~+$/, ''); //$ marks the end of a string
                            // ~+$ means: all ~ characters at the end of a string
```

Comment: If you want to trim whitespace do `s1 = s1.replace(/\s+$/, '')`

Answer (score 6):

There are no trim, ltrim, or rtrim functions in Javascript. Many libraries provide them, but generally they will look something like:

```
str.replace(/~*$/, '');
```

For right trims, the following is generally faster than a regex because of how regex deals with end characters in most browsers:

```
function rtrim(str, ch)
{
  let i = str.length;
  while (i-- && str.charAt(i) === ch);
  return str.substring(0, i + 1);
}

console.log(rtrim("moo", "x"));
console.log(rtrim("moo", "o"));
console.log(rtrim("oo", "o"));
```

Comment: Your function is wrong, in case of ``str`` contains only ``ch`` chars

Comment: Well, spotted! It's also over 10 years old at this point. :-D I edited it with a fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can modify the String prototype if you like. Modifying the String prototype is generally frowned upon, but I personally prefer this method, as it makes the code cleaner IMHO.

```
String.prototype.rtrim = function(s) { 
    return this.replace(new RegExp(s + "*$"),''); 
};
```

Then call...

```
var s1 = "this is a test~";
var s = s1.rtrim('~');
alert(s);
```

Comment: It's frowned upon for a reason. Don't do this!

Comment: @Evert Why is that?

Comment: @Javid You're polluting the global namespace, which can cause collisions with others and break scripts that expect a standard library. What's the big drawback of doing: `rtrim(foo, s)` vs `foo.rtrim(s)` ?

Comment: This was written 9 years ago. I would never recommend modifying the prototype of `String` today.

Answer (score 5):

IMO this is the best way to do a right/left trim and therefore, having a full functionality for trimming (since javascript supports `string.trim` natively)

```
String.prototype.rtrim = function (s) {
    if (s == undefined)
        s = '\\s';
    return this.replace(new RegExp("[" + s + "]*$"), '');
};
String.prototype.ltrim = function (s) {
    if (s == undefined)
        s = '\\s';
    return this.replace(new RegExp("^[" + s + "]*"), '');
};
```

Usage example:

```
var mystring = '   jav '
var r1 = mystring.trim();      // result = 'jav'
var r2 = mystring.rtrim();     // result = '   jav'
var r3 = mystring.rtrim(' v'); // result = '   ja'
var r4 = mystring.ltrim();     // result = 'jav '
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution using a regular expression:

```
"hi there~".replace(/~*$/, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str.trimEnd();
str.trimRight();
```

These are currently stage 4 proposals expected to be part of ES2019. They work in NodeJS and several browsers.

See below for more info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimEnd

Comment: Seems to be supported in all real browsers by now. Note that `trimEnd()` is the name consistent with `padEnd()`, while `trimRight()` is left as a legacy alias for compatibility with some browsers.

Comment: Oh, shoot, though question was asking how to trim a specific character, not whitespace

Answer (score 0):

This is old, I know. But I don't see what's wrong with substr...?

```
function rtrim(str, length) {
  return str.substr(0, str.length - length);
}
```

Comment: The only problem here is that there could be any number of characters at the end of the string... say instead of `this is test~` they happened to have `this is test~~~` or even none `this is test`. Your case does however work nicely for trimming a set number of characters from the string, regardless of what the character may be

Answer (score 0):

This removes a specified string or character from the right side of a string

```
function rightTrim(sourceString,searchString) 
{ 
    for(;;) 
    {
        var pos = sourceString.lastIndexOf(searchString); 
        if(pos === sourceString.length -1)
        {
            var result  = sourceString.slice(0,pos);
            sourceString = result; 
        }
        else 
        {
            break;
        }
    } 
    return sourceString;  
}
```

Please use like so:

```
rightTrim('sourcecodes.....','.'); //outputs 'sourcecodes'
rightTrim('aaabakadabraaa','a');   //outputs 'aaabakadabr'
```

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:

```
function rtrim(str: string, ch: string): string
{
    var i:number = str.length - 1; 
    
    while (ch === str.charAt(i) && i >= 0) i--
    
    return str.substring(0, i + 1);
}

const tests = ["/toto/", "/toto///l/", "/toto////", "/////", "/"]

tests.forEach(test => {
    console.log(`${test} = ${rtrim(test, "/")}`)
})
```

Gives

```
"/toto/ = /toto"
"/toto///l/ = /toto///l"
"/toto//// = /toto"
"///// = "
"/ = "
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library. It is a JavaScript utility library, There are some [trim functions](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#trimEnd). You can use:

```
_.trimEnd('this is a test~', '~')
```