# RTrim in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am having a problem with jQuery's trim.  I have a string such at in jQuery:

```
var string1;
string1 = "one~two~";
```

How do I trim the trailing tilde?

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript.  This has nothing to do with jQuery, it's just JavaScript.

Comment: If only there was a way to write javascript in jquery code somewhere...

Comment: Do you want a string without the tilde or an array with 'one' and 'two
?

Comment: @dotweb: He wants to trim the `~` from the end of the string.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked *trailing*. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript need to do a right trim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141718/javascript-need-to-do-a-right-trim)

Comment: What if the ~ in the problem is a comma instead?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The [`.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) method of jQuery refers to whitespace ..

> **Description**: Remove the whitespace from the beginning and end of a string.

---

You need

```
string1.replace(/~+$/,'');
```

This will remove all trailing `~`.

So `one~two~~~~~` would also become `one~two`

Comment: This will strip ~ at the beginning too, but just if there is a ~ at the end.

Comment: @Armin: No it won't.  It matches one or more `~` followed by the end of the string.

Comment: @armin, no it won't because of the `$` at the end. This means that the series of `~` must  be at the end of the string..

Comment: I have tested it wrong (with global flag). Sorry! Nice expression :)

Comment: @Armin, no problem .. although it will not remove the leading `~` with global flag either :) You probably missed the `$` when testing..

Comment: I have testet with http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ But the "onkeydown" event seems to be buggy, when I changed the source value.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder [not only jQuery, but programming in general](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimming_%28computer_programming%29) But i agree that, conceptually, trimming applies to much more :)

Comment: @Armin, good to know :) (*maybe you could contact the author of the page*)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder fair enough.. :)

Comment: Great answer, deeply useful!

Answer (score 10):

Just use the javascript replace to change the last string into nothing:

```
string1.replace(/~+$/g,"");
```

Answer (score 9):

IMO this is the best way to do a right/left trim and therefore, having a full functionality for trimming (since javascript supports `string.trim` natively)

```
String.prototype.rtrim = function (s) {
    if (s == undefined)
        s = '\\s';
    return this.replace(new RegExp("[" + s + "]*$"), '');
};
String.prototype.ltrim = function (s) {
    if (s == undefined)
        s = '\\s';
    return this.replace(new RegExp("^[" + s + "]*"), '');
};
```

Usage example:

```
var str1 = '   jav ~'
var r1 = mystring.rtrim('~'); // result = '   jav ' <= what OP is requesting
var r2 = mystring.rtrim(' ~'); // result = '   jav'
var r3 = mystring.ltrim();      // result = 'jav ~'
```

*P.S.* If you are specifying a parameter for `rtrim` or `ltrim`, make sure you use a regex-compatible string. For example if you want to do a `rtrim` by `[`, you should use: `somestring.rtrim('\\[')`
If you don't want to escape the string manually, you can do it using a regex-escape function if you will. See [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/492352).

Answer (score 4):

One option:

```
string1 = string1.substring(0,(string1.length-1));
```

long way around it .. and it jsut strips the last character .. not the tilde specifically..

Comment: He wants a function that functions like `Trim()` but with `~` instead of whitespace.

Answer (score -1):

```
var myStr = "One~Two~Three~Four~"     
var strLen = myStr.length;
myStr = myStr.slice(0,strLen-1);
alert (myStr);
```

This will delete the last character in the string.  Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score -3):

```
string1 = string1.substring(0, string1.length - 1);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Comment: This would strip every char, which is the last one. This is not what he asked for!

Comment: Actually, he did not specify that, so his question is subject to interpretation.

Answer (score -6):

You can use `substring` javascript method.

Try this

```
var string1 = "one~two~";
string1 = $.trim(string1).substring(0, string1.length -1);
```

Comment: This will trim any character off the end of the input string, not only a ~ as requested.