# Javascript remove extra underscores at the end of a string only

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a requirement to remove extra underscores from a string. The condition is if they occur at the very end of the string only.

As an example, we have DELL_  and DELL__  that needs to be changed to DELL.

I was considering using str.replace but I need to match cases specifically if it occurs at the end of the string and not all occurrences in that string. Also, I only want to run this script IF it detects the extra underscores.

I need to have some logic such as IF ( hasExtraUnderscores ) { remove extra underscores }

How can I do this in javascript?

NOTE: We are unable to use JQuery and need to do this in native javascript if possible.

Comment: `str = str.replace(/_+$/, "");`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116558/fastest-method-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string

Comment: not a dupe of that question because it needs to trim underscores & not remove internal ones

Comment: Never said it was a dupe :)

Comment: Dupe of this one rtrim in javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791394/rtrim-in-javascript

Comment: I am unable to use JQUERY in this case. The duplicate question has an answer but it is in jquery. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

[Try this](https://regex101.com/r/lF0oA4/1)

```
var str = 'DELL_'
alert(str.replace(/_+$/,'');
```