# How can I ltrim and rtrim select characters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

So I am trying to figure out how I can remove a select set of characters on the end of a string. I've tried some general 'solutions' like `str.replace` or creating a rtrim, but I kept seeing some situation in which it wouldn't work.

Possible inputs might be:

```
\r\n some random text \r\n
\r\n some random text
some random text \r\n
some random text
```

Only the first and the third line should be affected by this function.
Basicly I'm looking for a rtrim function that takes as a parameter, the value/character set that should be trimmed.

I think it might be something way too obvious that I don't see, but at this point I feel like I could use some help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RTrim in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791394/rtrim-in-javascript)

Comment: does the order of `\r` and `\n` matter or are you looking to replace just `\r\n` in that order, at the end of the line?

Comment: @JosephMarikle It represent a breakline (if I'm correct) in Windows, so it should be the seuqence

Comment: Alright.  That makes sense.  If it were a more generic newline replacement I would have suggested a character class instead, but it sounds like this is a very specific use case.

Comment: Question says `ltrim` and `rtrim` but description says only `rtrim`. What is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following piece of code to do that for you:

```
var a = "\r\n some random text \r\n";
a = a.replace(new RegExp('\r\n$'), '');
```

Here, `$` matches end of input.

You can refer to the regular expressions guide [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to find out more about regex in JS.

**EDIT:**

If you **really** need a function for this:

```
var rTrimRegex = new RegExp('\r\n$');
var rTrim = function(input){
    return input.replace(rTrimRegex, '');
}
```

And then use it inside your code maybe like:

```
var str = 'my name is foo\r\n\r\n';
str = rTrim(str);
```

Comment: I was more thinking in a way of `str.rtrim('\r\n')` but your code works flawless! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @BasPauw oh okay. Glad I could help. You can browse through other regex special characters and their uses as well, might help a lot.